# How to update value of Array.xml in android when data is come from server

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

I want to update my array.xml programmatically when data from server.

My MainActivity.java:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

//private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private Toolbar mToolbar;
ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
int arraylistvalue = 0;
ArrayList<String> arraylist1,arraylist2,arraylist3,arrayList4,arrayList5;
int cnt = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] mItemHeaders = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array_expandable_level_one);

    Collections.addAll(listDataHeader, mItemHeaders);
    ExpandableListView mExpandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
    if (mExpandableListView != null) {
        ParentLevelAdapter parentLevelAdapter = new ParentLevelAdapter(this, listDataHeader);
        mExpandableListView.setAdapter(parentLevelAdapter);
    }


    arraylist1  = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylist2  = new ArrayList<String>();
    arraylist3  = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList4 =  new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList5 =  new ArrayList<String>();
    new ProductsAsynTask().execute("http://opencart.codeniques.com/shopping/?route=feed/web_api/menu&key=test123$");


}
public class ProductsAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("In onPreExceute","");
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, Please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(String... param){
        try{
            Log.d("In doInBackground","");

            HttpClient client= new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(param[0]);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(status == 200){
                Log.d("Status",""+status);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("categories");

                for(int i = 0;i < jArray.length();i++){
                    cnt++;
                    Log.d("value of array",jArray.length()+"");
                    Log.d("Value of i",""+i);

                    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jArray.getJSONObject(i);




                    arraylist1.add(jsonObject1.getString("name"));
                    //data1 = jsonObject1.getString("name");
                    //      Log.d("hello ",data1);

                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject1.getJSONArray("children");
                    //           JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("children");

                    for(int j=0;j<jsonArray.length();j++){

                        JSONObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(j);

                        arraylist2.add(jsonObject2.getString("name"));
                        //  data2 = jsonObject2.getString("name");
                        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonObject2.getJSONArray("children_lv3");

                        for(int k=0;k<jsonArray1.length();k++){
                            JSONObject jsonObject3 = jsonArray1.getJSONObject(k);

                            arraylist3.add(jsonObject3.getString("name"));
                            arrayList4.add(jsonObject3.getString("href"));
                           /*  data3 = jsonObject3.getString("name");
                             data4 = jsonObject3.getString("href");   */
                        }
                        arrayList5.add(jsonObject2.getString("href"));
                        // data5 = jsonObject2.getString("href");
                    }
                }

            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e("Error IOException :",e.getMessage());
        }catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("Error JSONException",e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        dialog.dismiss();
  /*      expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
        expListView.setAdapter(new ParentLevel());*/
        Log.d("Counter value",""+cnt);
    }
}

public class ParentLevel extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1)
    {
        return arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CustExpListview SecondLevelexplv = new CustExpListview(MainActivity.this);
        SecondLevelexplv.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter());
        SecondLevelexplv.setGroupIndicator(null);
        return SecondLevelexplv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        int columr = arraylist1.size();
        return columr;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }


    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            tv.setText("");
            tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            tv.setPadding(10, 7, 7, 7);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds()
    {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

public class CustExpListview extends ExpandableListView
{

    int intGroupPosition, intChildPosition, intGroupid;

    public CustExpListview(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
    {
        widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(960, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(600, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tv.setText("child");
        tv.setPadding(15, 5, 5, 5);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        tv.setLayoutParams(new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
    {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        tv.setText("-->Second Level");
        tv.setPadding(12, 7, 7, 7);
        tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

My array.xml is here:-

```
<resources>
<string-array name="items_array_expandable_level_one">
    <item>Level 1.1</item>
    <item>Level 1.2</item>
    <item>Level 1.3</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="items_array_expandable_level_one_one_child">
    <item>Level 1.1.1</item>
    <item>Level 1.1.2</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="items_array_expandable_level_one_two_child">
    <item>Level 1.2.1</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="items_array_expandable_other_child">
    <item>Second Level 01</item>
    <item>Second Level 02</item>
    <item>Second Level 03</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="items_array_expandable_level_three">
    <item>Child Level 01</item>
    <item>Child Level 02</item>
</string-array>
```

How to update my list when data is come. please help me i am new in android developing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No! The arrays I mean in your previous question is not the arrays.xml file (this file can be considered a source of array data). What you need here is how to populate the arrays such as "mItemHeaders"...with the response data receiving from server. Then, you don't need the arrays.xml anymore.

Comment: can you edit my question??

Comment: I'm on mobile now, sorry can't help. I suggest you search more in SO about questions relating to Retrofit, Volley, OkHttp or HttpUrlConnection. There will be many sample codes that you can learn. Goodluck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resources stored in application are generated during compile-time and are `read-only` during runtime. You can't modify them.

You could try to use SQlite database for storing information. The first time you run application it will take data from XML Array and store in database. Next time when you update from the server you can just add/modify your database.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot modify resources at run time. You may want to consider storing the xml somewhere and querying it when you want the values instead of the resources on android.

You would store the xml on the device, use [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) to create a means of accessing those files, and then create a [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) object to use in the same way that you are doing already.